Comparing the angle between PCA loading plots
I am analyzing temperature, precipitation, and snow depth in three datasets. I used PCA for the analysis, and I obtained angles of 13.1°, 19.6°, and 102.0° between precipitation and snow depth for datasets 1, 2, and 3, respectively. However, I was uncertain about comparing these angles, so I projected these PCA plots onto a common coordinate system. Now, the angles are 11.5°, 18.1°, and 48.5°. This change has confused me, as for dataset 3, the correlation seems to have changed direction in the projection. Is there another way to compare the angles of different biplots? Can I use the absolute value (13.1°, 19.6°, and 102.0°) to measure the correlation and compare?

Welcome to the site!  Aren't the correlations among components irrespective of your projection method?

I sadly realise it now. I thought it will be easier to compare different PCA by projecting in same co-ordinate. I only noticed it when I started getting weird correlation between variables.  Can anyone help me with how can I compare correlation between multivariable datasets (eg, relation between temperature, precipitation and snd snow depth in three different datasets)
